# Linker errors when migrating from xc32 2.10 to 2.15

Tags: pic, microchip

For reasons that I cannot track down, there seems to be some substantial differences in the linker between 2.10 and 2.15.  After fixing up some multiple defines with "extern", I've come to the point where I'm just baffled on what is different.  I have functional code that works with 2.10, but with 2.15 there are some vector conflicts.

```
/Applications/microchip/xc32/v2.15/bin/xc32-gcc -mprocessor=32MZ2048EFH144 -DXPRJ_default=default -legacy-libc -Wl,--defsym=_min_heap_size=65536,--no-code-in-dinit,--no-dinit-in-serial-mem -o bin/serial-r312-flash.elf obj/flash_interrupts.o obj/flash_main.o         
obj/main.o: In function `__vector_dispatch_24':
main.c:(.vector_24+0x0): multiple definition of `__vector_dispatch_24'
obj/flash_interrupts.o:interrupts.c:(.vector_24+0x0): first defined here
obj/flash_main.o: In function `__vector_dispatch_9':
main.c:(.vector_9+0x0): multiple definition of `__vector_dispatch_9'
obj/flash_interrupts.o:interrupts.c:(.vector_9+0x0): first defined here
/Applications/microchip/xc32/v2.15/bin/bin/gcc/pic32mx/4.8.3/../../../../bin/pic32m-ld: Link terminated due to previous error(s).
collect2: error: ld returned 255 exit status
make: *** [flash] Error 255
```

I have attempted to make the vectors externs, but that did not help in the least.

```
//interrupt.h
extern void __attribute__((vector(_TIMER_2_VECTOR), interrupt(ipl7AUTO), nomips16))SampleTimerHandler(void);

//interrupt.c
void __attribute__((vector(_TIMER_2_VECTOR), interrupt(ipl7AUTO), nomips16)){}
```

In main.c, I basically have a loop.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining your ISRs like that:

`void __ISR(_USB_VECTOR, IPL1SOFT) USB_ISR() {`

Builds clean on mine with -Wall . Also, I believe `nomips16` is the new default.

EDIT: also, see comments. Apparently, an attempt to re-declare the ISR in a header file has been a contributing factor.

Comment: I gave it a try and it compiled and ran fine on 2.10, but still dies on 2.15.  I wonder if the linker script is bad for the PIC32MZ2048EFH144.

Comment: I've had g++ dislike `__attribute__` in ISR def recently. Since xc32 and ++ are the same gcc I thought they could've introduced the same bug in both during upgrade :-). I forgot to mention that you (I) don't need a declaration for the ISR in .h - this could be another issue since it's a C function and you're trying to rename it with the decl.

Comment: The .h was causing the problem with 2.15 but not 2.10.  Added this a note to your answer and I'll accept it.  I think it's all good information.

Comment: Did you remove both `__attribute__` and declaration to make it happy?

Comment: I didn't have to do that.  It just needed have the ISRs redeclared, anything with ((coherent)) to be made external and pull the header for the interrupts out.  Looking back at my SVN revisions, most of those changes were there from when I went from 1.42 to 2.05.  I guess the design team liked some of the older ways.  I probably should try pulling `__attribute__` too, but it's working.